# Capybara Ambiguity Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My application is based on Rails 3 in action which have devise for user authentication i got this error. How could this error be solved ?

```
bin/cucumber features/signing_up.feature
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Using the default profile...
Feature: Signing up
  In order to be attributed for my work
  As a user
  I want to be able to sign up

  Scenario: Signing up                                                 # features/signing_up.feature:6
    Given I am on the homepage                                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
    When I follow "Sign up"                                            # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
      Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching link "Sign up" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:57:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/signing_up.feature:8:in `When I follow "Sign up"'
    And I fill in "Email" with "user@ticketee.com"                     # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:60
    And I fill in "Password" with "password"                           # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:60
    And I fill in "Password confirmation" with "password"              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:60
    And I press "Sign up"                                              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:52
    Then I should see "You have signed up successfully."               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105
    Then I should see "Please confirm your account before signing in." # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/signing_up.feature:6 # Scenario: Signing up

1 scenario (1 failed)
8 steps (1 failed, 6 skipped, 1 passed)
0m0.272s
```

step definition:57

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end
```

routes.rb

```
Ticketee::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  get '/awaiting_confirmation', :to => "users#confirmation", :as => 'confirm_user'

  resources :projects do
    resources :tickets
  end
  root :to => "projects#index"

  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "base#index"
    resources :users
  end
```

that is the routes.rb which getting from the book , and in the book the test is passing but not passing with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the link is within some other styling like a class or id, you can use:

```
within(<whatever class or id>) do
  click_link(link)
end
```

Alternatively to force it to click the first link you can use `first(:link, link).click`.
If you use this approach, you will need something like `all(link)[1].click` to hit the "Sign up" button later.

Comment: i have tried `first(:link, link).click` but it raises `uninitialized constant RegistrationsController (ActionController::RoutingError)` but i have this controller already and on previous chapters of the book my current step in the question was working good ,so maybe the first link is not the corrent one , is there a way to make it use the second link ?

Comment: See the extra bit I put in my answer above at the end - `all(link)[1].click` will hit the second link.

Comment: i have added it so my step like :
`When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  first(:link, link).click
  all(link)[1].click
end`
and it raises `uninitialized constant RegistrationsController (ActionController::RoutingError)` again

Comment: BTW, the `uninitialized constant` error you are getting is nothing to do with clicking the wrong link - that is a problem with your `routes.rb`.

Comment: Does `RegistrationsController` exist?  If it does, post your `routes.rb` file please.

Comment: It cannot find your registrations controller.  Could you check that the first line of this controller is `class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController` and that the file name is `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`.

Comment: when i use `all(link)[1].click` under `first(:linl, link).click` it raises `undefined method click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: it solved but i am not having `all(link)[1].click` is it good or bad ?